# Unable to access SBS 2008 internal Web Sites from inside LAN

Tags: cisco, windows-sbs-2008

I have just completed a network migration from a consumer modem/router to Cisco 887VA and all seems to be up and running aside from some last remaining issues that I can't seem to sort out.

The default SBS 2008 Internal Web site was previously reachable via browser by all hosts on the network either wired to the switch or on the WLAN AP however since migration I am unable to resolve that address from any host.

All hosts can can log into their SBS user accounts, and ping and RDP to the server. I'm wondering if it's something to do with NAT but am unsure how the NAT works inside the LAN. The server and all hosts are on the same VLAN all the way through.

Similar to using:
    ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.2 80 interface Dialer0 80

Could I use:
    ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.2 80 interface FastEthernet0 80

to redirect traffic from Fa0 (which trunks the switch and subsequently the WLAN) to the SBS server @ 192.168.0.2 on Fa1?

Comment: Are you talking about the default SBS08 web site at the URL http://companyweb?  If so, I assume you've double-checked DNS and IIS, right?

Comment: Yep the default companyweb URL that's correct. SBS08 is handling DHCP and is handing out the two DNS addresses of our ISP to the clients. As for IIS, it's not something I have much experience in maintaining. Any tips on where to look? I assumed it was a routing issue since the issue came up after I changed the router but there may be something config side on SBS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, you are handing out the DNS servers for your ISP instead of your SBS2008 box?  Basically what you've done is bypass your local DNS and ask your ISP who "companyweb" is and of course it can't resolve it. The only machine that can do that is your SBS2008 box.

You should point internal clients to your SBS2008 server for DNS in DHCP and in DNS on the SBS2008 box setup forwarders for external DNS resolution to point to your ISP.  This way, the SBS server will answer if it can, and if it can't it will go ask your ISPs servers who will go get an answer for it.

Comment: Yeah, it's bedtime.  Trashing my answer in favor of yours now.  ;)

Comment: Come to think of it that makes a lot of sense haha. Will have to wait a few days to try it out and see. Thanks!

Comment: @KatherineVillyard, a good chunk of the time I trash my answer in favor of yours.

Comment: That was spot on, just had time to adjust the DNS forwarding and the DNS info for the DHCP and we're back with full functionality! Much appreciated :)

Comment: YAY!!  Glad to hear it.